# How can I keep a data when ON DUPLICATE KEY executes?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

**Here is the scenario:** I'm trying to make a mechanism on some text comments. For example I want to calculate the most used words in some comments. Here is [my code](https://3v4l.org/XlcBr):

```
function cleanWord( &$word ){
    $word = trim($word, "'\".!<>{}()-/\*&^%$#@+~ ");
}

// list of comments
$arr_str =  [
            "  this!! is     the first &test message./",
            "*Second ^message this (is) ",
            "'another\ **message*** !\"}& it is. also the favorite one (message)."
            ];

// To join array's items      
$str = implode(" ", $arr_str);

// To chop the string based on the space
$words = explode(" ",$str);

// To remove redundant character(s)
array_walk($words, 'cleanWord');

// To remove empty array elements
$words = array_filter($words);

print_r($words);

/* Output:
Array
(
    [2] => this
    [3] => is
    [8] => the
    [9] => first
    [10] => test
    [11] => message
    [12] => Second
    [13] => message
    [14] => this
    [15] => is
    [17] => another
    [18] => message
    [20] => it
    [21] => is
    [22] => also
    [23] => the
    [24] => favorite
    [25] => one
    [26] => message
)
```

As you see in the fiddle, `$words` contains an array include of all words from those comments. I also have a table in database that I insert words in it like this:

```
foreach( $words as $word ){
    $db->query("INSERT INTO words (word) 
                       VALUES $word
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE used_num = used_num + 1");
                -- there is a unique index on "word" column
}

/* Output:
// words
+----+----------+----------+
| id |   word   | used_num |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | this     | 2        |
| 2  | is       | 3        |
| 3  | the      | 2        |
| 4  | first    | 1        |
| 5  | test     | 1        |
| 6  | message  | 4        |
| .  | .        | .        |
| .  | .        | .        |
| .  | .        | .        |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Then I select the most used words like this:

```
SELECT * FROM words
ORDER BY used_num DESC
LIMIT $limit
```

---

**What's my question?!** In reality, that array looks like this:

```
$arr_str =  [
               ["  this!! is     the first &test message./", "Jack", "1488905152"],
               ["*Second ^message this (is) ", "Peter", "1488901178"],
               ["'another\ **message*** !\"}& it is. also the favorite one (message).", "John", "1488895116"]
            ];
```

As you see, each comment also has both an **author** and an **published-time**. Now I want:

- to make a filtering system based on that unix-timestamp. *(For example getting most used words between x and y times)*
- to make a list of authors for each word. *(For example, the word of "message" is used 4 times in those comments. Now I want to access a list of those comments' authors, i.e. [Jack, Peter, John])*

Have you any suggestion about the algorithm of implementing these^ ?

Comment: i would add a third column with the timestamp of the message and a fourth with the author (on the words table) so you could group to get the total usage, filter by timestamp values and then group or get the concat authors from the word.

Comment: @LordNeo In this case I'll be faced with a huge dataset.

Comment: If you want to filter based on these criteria, then you need to store the additional data

Comment: @Shadow Trust me, I knew that. But how exactly? In the other table? In the same table by adding new columns?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. Do you need to maintain a word master list for any reason?

Comment: Btw, you just expressed your reservation with the 2nd option, which leaves you with the first one.

Comment: @Shadow *"the first one"* means storing the other data into a new table?

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant. Again, the answer boils down whether you need a master table of words. But only **you** can answer this question

Comment: @Shadow I see. To sum up, yes, I need a master list for every word (it should be containing some data *(like comment_id, comment_author_id, comment_time_published) which the word is used in)*. Now what's your suggestion? An new table? Or adding a new row in the current table and adding some new columns to keep other data?

Comment: You are mixing up master data and transactional data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to clean the words:

```
$comments = [
  "  this!! is     the first &test message./",
  "*Second ^message this (is) ",
  "'another\ **message*** !\"}& it is. also the favorite one (message)."
];

foreach($comments as $k => $str){
  preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z]+)/', $str, $matches);
  $exploded[] = $matches[0];
}

print_r($exploded);
```

---

However, you want to attach data to each "word", you'd have to add a table first. Your table has a primary key for each word, good because we dont want to store excess data.

Now for a second table (`worddata`):

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id |  wordid  | commentid |
+----+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | 2         |
+----+----------+-----------+
          |          \-> refers to the primary key of the comments table
          |
          -> refers to 'this'
```

Now I'm presuming you have a table where all comments are stored (going to call it `comments`), which are linked to a time of posting and have a author id.

In essence, fill this table like so:

```
SELECT comments_id, comments_text FROM comments
```

Filter your words and insert them into the table:

```
INSERT INTO worddata (wordid, comment_id)
```

I'd recommend to use a temporarily table for this because each word in each comment should have its own row which could sum up to a lot of data. The `wd.wordid = 1` should refer to the word `'this'` according to your `wordlist` table.

You can select all the comments between dates if that value is already known and only insert the words from those comments.

---

Now you can join table data:

```
SELECT c.id, c.userid, c.created
FROM `comments` as c
  JOIN `worddata` as wd on wd.commentid = c.userid
WHERE wd.wordid = 1
```

Now this example should return all the comments id's where the word is `this`. If you want to filter by `author` you should change or add `c.userid = #` to the `WHERE` clause. Selecting between dates can be done with `c.created > NOW() - 3600` for the comments in the last hour.

Of course you can select more data if needed but again this is more of a join example than a copy paste-able code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But you know, I want to keep words like these: `h0w`, `th!s`. Anyway I'm ok with my current `cleanWord` function. I'm trying to solve those two cases in the end of my question.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Shadow Sorry, I hit the enter key without focusing on the text area. Took some edits, but the general idea is there.

Comment: @Shafizadeh keep in mind, using this method the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` is irrelevant. Simply count rows where `wordid = #` from the `worddata` table.

Answer (score 1):

A table like this may work:

```
+----+----------+----------+--------------+
| id |   word   | author   | timestamp    |
+----+----------+----------+--------------+
| 1  | this     | author1  |  1488905152  |
| 2  | is       | author1  |  1488905152  |
| 3  | the      | author1  |  1488905152  |
| 4  | first    | author1  |  1488905152  |
| 5  | test     | author1  |  1488905152  |
| 6  | message  | author1  |  1488905152  |
| 7  | Second   | author2  |  1488905152  |
| 8  | this     | author2  |  1488905152  |
| 9  | the      |  .       |              |
| .  |  .       |  .       |              |
| .  |  .       |  .       |              |
| .  |  .       |  .       |              |
+----+----------+----------+--------------+
```

To make the queries faster you can put index on the columns.

Other approach would be to keep your table and have a second table with id, idWord, author , timestamp. And make joins when you need data for author or timestamp. In this case you can keep a small datatable that works only for words and the number of apparition, and an extension table with more details about their apparition.